# Adding multiple sets of JLabel and JTextBox to the same line in Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

I'm building an equation solver that allows the user to enter a system of equations and then get the answer. So, I need to build a GUI that allows the user to enter the set of equations. I decided to go about doing this from scratch. Here's what my code looks like:

```
private JFrame frame;
private JTextField[][] text;
private JLabel label;
private JLabel equalLabel;
private JLabel plusLabel;
private JTextField answerText;

private void displayGetEquations(int total)
{
frame = new JFrame("Enter Equations");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    equalLabel = new JLabel();
    equalLabel.setText(" = ");
    plusLabel = new JLabel();
    plusLabel.setText(" + ");
    answerText = new JTextField();
    answerText.setColumns(2);
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,10));
    text = new JTextField[3][3];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++)
    {
 panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        for(int j = 0 ; j < 3 ; j++)
        {
            text[i][j] = new JTextField();
            text[i][j].setColumns(2);
            label = new JLabel();
            Font font = label.getFont();
            Font boldFont = new Font(font.getFontName(), Font.BOLD, font.getSize());
            label.setFont(boldFont);
            label.setText("x");
            panel.add(text[i][j]);
            panel.add(label);
            panel.add(plusLabel);
        }
        panel.add(equalLabel);
        panel.add(answerText);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.revalidate();          
        frame.repaint(); 

    }
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

This is what I get when I run the above code:

[image: What I get when I run the above code]

But I am not getting the desired output, which, I would like to be something like this:
[image]

This was made using the ***drag and drop*** feature of **NetBeans**What am I doing wrong? Is what I want even possible? 
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks !

(This was made using the ***drag and drop*** feature of **NetBeans**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a little bit confusing and the one posted here isn't a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as it lacks a `main` method and imports and a variable `panel`, as well as it's giving me a different output than the one you posted:

[image]

From your example-output images I made 2 approaches, one which uses multiple `JPanel` with a `FlowLayout` inside another one with `BoxLayout` and another one which uses a single `JPanel` with a `GridLayout`. Another approach could be using `GridBagLayout`

[image]

I used `x`, `y` and `z` variable names because I thought you were using an equation solving program or something like that.

Here's the code that produces the above outputs:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class MultipleComponentsInRow {

    public static final int ROWS = 3;
    public static final int COLS = 4;

    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel flowLayoutPanel;
    private JPanel gridLayoutPanel;

    private JTextField[][] flowFields;
    private JTextField[][] gridFields;

    private void createAndShowGui() {
        frame = new JFrame("Multiple Components In Row");

        flowFields = new JTextField[ROWS][COLS];
        gridFields = new JTextField[ROWS][COLS];

        flowLayoutPanel = new JPanel();
        flowLayoutPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(flowLayoutPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        gridLayoutPanel = new JPanel();
        gridLayoutPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(ROWS, 7));

        for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
                flowFields[i][j] = new JTextField(2);
                gridFields[i][j] = new JTextField(2);
            }
        }

        //FlowLayout approach
        for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
            JPanel pane = new JPanel();
            pane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
                pane.add(flowFields[i][j]);
                switch (j) {
                    case 0:
                        pane.add(new JLabel(" x + "));
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        pane.add(new JLabel(" y + "));
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        pane.add(new JLabel(" z = "));
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            flowLayoutPanel.add(pane);
        }

        //GridLayout approach
        for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
                gridLayoutPanel.add(gridFields[i][j]);
                switch (j) {
                    case 0:
                        gridLayoutPanel.add(new JLabel(" x + "));
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        gridLayoutPanel.add(new JLabel(" y + "));
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        gridLayoutPanel.add(new JLabel(" z = "));
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2, 5, 5));

        flowLayoutPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK), "Flow Layout"));
        gridLayoutPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED), "Grid Layout"));

        frame.add(flowLayoutPanel);
        frame.add(gridLayoutPanel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MultipleComponentsInRow().createAndShowGui();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about the theory here. Big picture view: You have a frame with a panel right? Why not have a frame with 3 panels? The frame layout will be a vertical stackpane and the each panel will be a horizontal layout with the 4 textfields. You may want consider using JavaFX where you could do something like:

...

```
HBox hBox1 = new Hbox();
hBox1.getChildern.addAll(new Textfield(), new Textfield(), new Textfield());
... //repeat 2 more times

Vbox vbox = new VBox(hBox1, hBox2, hBox3);

...
```

Then you have 3x horizontal layouts contained in 1 vertical layout.